# SSMS 2008 Estimated Execution Plan, Execution Plan Analysis tooltip disappears

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio 2008, when I run an estimated execution plan, I right click in the results to display the Execution Plan Analysis.

On the left of the estimated execution plan are icons that allow you to see the information about the plan.  To see the text you have to hover your mouse over the icons.  The text displays in tooltips.  However, the tooltips disappear after a couple of seconds and I have to move my mouse away and re-hover.  This makes if very difficult to read.

Is there another way or place to see this text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the answer is to not use "Execution Plan Analysis".  Instead, after clicking "Display Estimated Execution Plan", hove your mouse over the first icon in the execution plan and look at the value in "Estimated Subtree Cost".

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this information is available in the Properties Panel. Just click F4 and the panel will show the information from the plan or, if you click on an operator, the currently selected operator.

That said, you could try the free [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp). All of this information (and a ton more!) is presented to you in different tabs, many with grid formats that support sorting. Much easier than trying to remember what you saw in the last operator and compare it to the current one.

*Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.*

Comment: I downloaded and installed but it didn't add the context menu even after restarting SSMS twice.  So I run the app manually with my sproc and I am not seeing what the added value is to the built in estimated execution plan.

Comment: You need to [download the SSMS add-in separately](http://downloads.sqlsentry.net/downloads/sqlsentryplanexplorer/SQLSentryPlanExplorerSSMSAddinSetup.msi). We did that because some people don't want the context menu in SSMS. [Here is a starting point for seeing the added benefits over the built-in plan](http://bit.ly/nXowyy). There are even more benefits when you generate an actual plan from within the tool (e.g. you get runtime metrics like CPU and duration, as well as table I/O, which you can't get from the built-in plan without adding all kinds of set options).